# Controlled and paged ldap_search in LDAP using ldapjs node library

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldapjs

We are looking for ldap_search parameter to fetch the results from particular page directly instead loading pages sequentially one after other. For example loading LDAP entries from 10th page directly by skipping 1st to 9th pages.

We have requirement where user should have control on page to loaded from the LDAP server. Hence we are looking for parameter which brings directly user requested page while using ldap_search with paged mode.

```
 filter: '(objectClass=user)',
 scope: 'sub',
  attributes: [
     "CN",
     "ou",
     "createTimestamp",
     "modifyTimestamp"      
   ],
   attrsOnly:true,
   sizeLimit:100,
   timeLimit:5,
   paged:true
};

client.search('DC=test,DC=com', opts, function(err, res) {...}
```

We are looking for parameter to load particular page directly instead loading all the pages from LDAP server to read some 10th page or 15th page.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Did you manage to solve this?